# How to set Distribution section in changes file using sbt-native-packager Debian plugin?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager, sbt-plugin

When I generate .deb and .changes files using JavaServerAppPackaging plugin, my changes file contains `Distribution: unknown`. 
How I can change that?